# Is there a way to change default action of a sensitive area in button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a calculator App in React and generally, it's ok, but...

If I hold it longer I notice that the click is confirmed if click-down had been on the button and click-up have been on the button

I know that margin is not clickable, but in this App I can't use, for example, position

[image]

**The point is that the button is animated and when click-up, cursor is not over the button. And I have a question that is there a way to prevent the whole problem in any way, so that it works the way it should?**

Here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/FloweDewolf/calculator

Here's the link to the calculator: [https://flowedewolf.github.io/calculator](https://flowedewolf.github.io/calculator/)

And thanks for every help!

Comment: But for what? Everything is included in this question, the links are just extra for someone who wants to see the source code

Comment: Why do you think I don't want the animation? I made it deliberately and I want it to stay. I'm not asking for recommendations, I'm asking for ways to make it work the way I want it to

Comment: **"The point is that the button is animated. And I have a question that is there a way to prevent that in any way"** - sorry if my English is inelegant, but you specifically asked how to prevent animation, or did you wish to "prevent" something else - what is a "sensitive area in a button" ... I asked my wife and she giggled

Answer (score 0):

One solution here would be to use a pseudo-element for the styling. This way the actual button bounds (red border) will stay in place. It also prevents writing additional logic to solve a styling issue.

```js
let count = 0;
function handleClick() {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = ++count;
}
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}

button::before {
 position: absolute;
 content: ' ';
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 4rem;
 width: 4rem;
 background: #ff9999;
 z-index: -1;
}
button:active::before {
 left: 1rem;
 top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()">Add 1</button>

<p>current count: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
```